# Used preprogrammed ECM

Tags: electronic-control-module

Bought a refurbished ECM pre programmed to my Vin number Bottom vehicle a year ago used used and have had trouble with engine light and limp mode in the last 6 months 6 months we have replaced about 10 different things because it keeps throwing codes to replace these things we figure it is the ECM When we tried to swap it out it was locked What do we do

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Quite literally, you're going to need to send it back to whomever you bought it from and get it re-coded or get a refund. There should be some sort of warranty on it from them. Also, we'd ask in the future if you could please use punctuation & capitalization, as this is very hard to read as it is.

Comment: Note that I edited your question as best I could to try to make it intelligible but there are still very important details missing.  Please EDIT the question and fill in those items.

Comment: Well I tried to edit it but it seems someone undid it.  Thanks....